# Vertical and horizontal align all content and elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have a div with some content, in this case 2 buttons and a paragraph.  I want to vertically and horizontally align all the elements and content inside that div by changing its CSS. How can I do this?

```
<style>
  .middle {
    What to type in here?
  }
</style>

<div class="middle">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Button 1">
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Button 2">
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, those `<input>` elements need to be self closing:  `<input type="button" value="Button 1" />`

Comment: How do you want to align it? everything in the middle, to the left etc. ?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - Why?

Comment: @Jeevan Jose - Yeah everything in the middle

Comment: Does .middle have a fix or fluid height?

Comment: Yes it's position in my real code is set to "fixed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this style:

```css
/* stretch them to window's height */
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

/* normalize them from default 8px to zero */
html, body, div, p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/* vertical align */
 body {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
.middle {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/* horizontal align */
.middle {
    text-align:center;
}
```

[jsfiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/n6522/2/)

Alternatively you can put all your html code into some container `div` and stylize it instead of the `body` tag:

[jsfiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/n6522/3/)

For completeness' sake, the simplest style where the content of the `.middle` division is centered and the height of the `.middle` also depends on its inner content can be made with the equal top and bottom paddings as follows:

```css
.middle {
    padding:5em 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[jsfiddle #3](http://jsfiddle.net/n6522/4/)

Comment: Thanks, the third example was the exact thing that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to this:

```
<div class="middle">
    <div id='mydiv'>
       <p>Hello</p>
       <input type="button" value="Button 1" />
       <input type="button" value="Button 2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS to

```
.middle
{
padding: 0;
}

#mydiv
{
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#mydiv *
{
display: block;
}

input[type='button']
{
margin: 0;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6522/1/

PS. The border and width is just to give you an idea. You don't need to add the first block.

Comment: It isn't vertical aligned at middle?

Comment: No not at the same line the breaks should still be there but I want everything in the middle vertical too

Comment: Yes, I accept this answer too, but I like the simplest solution which Stano came up with, check the jsfiddle #3 on his answer.